# printing outputs on everystep keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How can I print on every step to see outputs in Keras?

```
outputs = []
for layer in model.layers:
    keras_function = K.function([model.input], [layer.output])
    outputs.append([[model.input],keras_function([training_data, 1])])
print(outputs)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly do you need? By every step, do you mean Output of every Layer? Do you want that information for one Instance of Training Data or for Entire Training Data? Thanks!

Comment: You can consider this similar implementation from this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493222/