# saving multiple tensors in a file

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

I want to save the feature tensors that produce in middle layers of some DNN and use them for another training network. for example I fetch some input to alexnet and I get the middle layers feature vectors and save them in a file. then I want to use these tensors as input of another network. how can I save them?
I want to save them such that I can load them one by one.
thank you.

Comment: Can you share your code to generate your initial DNN? What you're asking for is definitely feasible, but it would be much easier to show it in an example.

Comment: Why is this tagged dotnetnuke?

Comment: what i want to do is to fetch middle feature tensors to some network like auto encoder to decrease dimensions of it. but I do not want retrain main DNN from scratch. and  I want to train another DNN to do that. so I need to have these tensors as input to the network. and now I am searching for a way to save them.

Comment: @niloo199: You can save trainable variables using ``checkpoints`` and load them later to your network. Furthermore, if you want to freeze them to avoid destroying them, you can freeze those layers to avoid further learning by ``layer.trainable = False``. If this helps you I can elaborate in the answer.

Comment: what I want is the output tensor of each layer. I think what you say save the weights of DNN layers. actually I want to feed some input to main network and then save the output of specific layer and use them as input of another network

Comment: @niloo1996: You can access each layer output by it's index or name, like this ``model.layers[index].output``. For example for the last layer, it is ``model.layers[-1].output``. This will give you the output tensor of a desired layer. Then you can save  anywhere you want, and feed them to another network.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507891/14290244) answer to your problem.

Comment: actually i want to know how to save them and access them as an input of another network?
using of these features is my question

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the outputs of all intermediate layers in a Sequential model by using the below code.

```
initial_model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(250, 250, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 5, strides=2, activation="relu"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
    ]
)
feature_extractor = keras.Model(
    outputs=[layer.output for layer in initial_model.layers]
)
```

For more details please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model#feature_extraction_with_a_sequential_model). Thank You.